# Java wait() and notifyAll() resume oldest Thread

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

My problem:

Lets say that i have class `A` with some variable `a`

And  class `B` with variables `prev` and `next`

In class `A` i want to make method `changeIfEqual(B myB)` which checks if `A.a == my_B.prev`, if so i change `A.a` to `my_B.next`. But if `A.a != my_B.prev` i want thread to `wait()` until continion is true and then execute the thread that have been waining for the longest time.

So I imagine `A.changeIfEqual(B myB)` should look like this:

```
public synchronized void changeIfEqual(B myB){
  while(this.a != myB.b_prev){
     wait();
  }
  notifyAll();
}
```

In this case the problem is how can I ensure that the oldest thread would be resume? (`wait()` and `notifyAll()` dont provide that)

Comment: If you've got several threads all awaiting the same event, then it _should not matter_ which one is awakened when the event happens. If it actually matters, then your solution to your problem probably is more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don’t. Which thread gets notified is up to the scheduler. If you replace the implicit locking (using synchronized) with ReentrantLock, then you can specify that the lock is fair. But that's not a perfect solution, see [the API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html):

> The constructor for this class accepts an optional fairness parameter. When set true, under contention, locks favor granting access to the longest-waiting thread. Otherwise this lock does not guarantee any particular access order. Programs using fair locks accessed by many threads may display lower overall throughput (i.e., are slower; often much slower) than those using the default setting, but have smaller variances in times to obtain locks and guarantee lack of starvation. Note however, that fairness of locks does not guarantee fairness of thread scheduling. Thus, one of many threads using a fair lock may obtain it multiple times in succession while other active threads are not progressing and not currently holding the lock. Also note that the untimed tryLock method does not honor the fairness setting. It will succeed if the lock is available even if other threads are waiting.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely must wake "consumer" threads in a particular order,* the thing to do would be to give each consumer its own `Semaphore`, and have each consumer put a reference to its semaphore into a queue before awaiting it.

```
class MyConsumer {
    private final Queue<Semaphore> sleep_q;
    private final Semaphore sleep_sem = new Semaphore(0);

    public MyConsumer(Queue sleep_q) {
        this.sleep_q = sleep_q;
    }

    private void waitToBeNotified() {
        sleep_q.add(sleep_sem);
        sleep_sem.acquire();
    }

    public void whatever() {
        doSomeStuff();
        waitToBeNotified();
        doSomeMoreStuff();
}
```

The producer can awaken the longest-waiting thread by popping a semaphore from the queue, and releasing a permit to it.

```
class MyProducer {
    private final Queue<Semaphore> sleep_q;

    public MyConsumer(Queue sleep_q) {
        this.sleep_q = sleep_q;
    }

    public void goForthAndProduceStuff() {
        while (...) {
            produceSomething();
            awakenAConsumer();
        }
    }

    private void awakenAConsumer() {
        Semaphore sem = sleep_q.poll();
        if (sem != null) {
            sem.release();
        }
    }

}
```

---

* But, see my comment on the original question.

Comment: Yes, but this is way beyond the original question.

Comment: @edharned, The only way to answer the OP's question without going "way beyond" would be to simply say, "You can't! Sorry, Have a nice day!" But, the OP was trying to solve a _problem_. IMO, it's probably an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), but it's not a difficult problem. Just for grins, I thought I would show how I would solve it.